# How to I shut down with VBS?

Tags: vbscript

I don’t know how to shut down my computer with vbs and when I tried to do it, it would just open a software and remove it and that’s is.

I was expecting to shut down but I did not do what i wanted to happened

```
X-msgbox ("Do you want to shut down?", 4+32, "Shutdown")
if x=6 then msgbox "ok", 0,"Shutdown"
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe""")
elseif x=7 then 
msgbox "ok",0,"Shutdown"
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It will shut down after 20 seconds.

```
Dim msg
Set WshShell=CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
msg=MsgBox("Shutdown?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion,"Shutdown")
If msg=6 Then
WshShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 20"
Else
MsgBox("Ok. Exiting",vbOkOnly,"Shutdown")
Wscript.Quit
End If
```

Comment: But I want it to do it quickly and no wait like the shutdown button

Comment: Then just change the 20 on the 5th line to any number of seconds you want.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to exit your program before the Shutdown will take effect. Thus, the `Wscript.Quit` is actually the important part.

Comment: No because the program isn't running anything after the MsgBox or running the shutdown command, therefore the Wscript.Quit is actually unnecessary.